# Cannot print PDF but can open it in Preview

Tags: pdf, preview, printing

I was trying to print [this document](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~frederic.klopp/cours/m1-4m030-16-17/4M030-semaine-09-01-17.pdf). It opens great in Preview but I cannot print it:

```
ERROR: undefined
OFFENDING COMMAND: firMf

STACK:

1185863205
-dictionary-
/CharStrings
...
```

Trying to print starting from another page leads to a similar error. Any idea? My printer works great on other similar material.

Note that this document is **just week 1 of 10** of a class and if I could screenshot and print the jpg page by page I would (I just care about printing) but there are 200 pages total so Im looking for another solution.

Comment: @PeterJ thanks a LOT but unfortunately it doesn't. Let me post an answer of what finally worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing pdftops (and associated tools) worked. It converted the pdf to ps which I could then open (unlike when I directly saved to .ps from Preview) and print

Comment: This worked for me also, thanks.  I downloaded pdftops here: https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html.  And watched the instructional video here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/videos/59894/Xpdf-PDFtoPS-Command-Line-Utility-to-Convert-a-PDF-File-to-PS-PostScript.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking Print in Preview, then at the bottom of the window press the drop-down labelled "PDF" and choose to "Save to Postscript".

Now open the Postscript file and print that. The file conversion should (hopefully) ensure that the offending command is gone when the Postscript file is converted back to PDF for printing.

Comment: so this works on normal pdf files but on this one I cannot open the .ps export :(

Comment: Hi @jisoegarrd, see my answer below (given by the teacher who wrote the pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when trying to print a boarding pass from WizzAir.

Opening the PDF in Adobe Acrobat Reader and printing from there instead of MacOS preview fixed the issue for me.